# Reacting when, by scrolling, an element enters the visible part of an overflowing DIV

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, overflow

My question is more of a "how would you approach this" type of question than me asking for specific code.

The current situation is this:

On my website, there is a section where I present my photography. The photos are shown inside an overflowing DIV; if the users wants to see more photos they can scroll through the overflow. User-interaction-wise I like this system a lot, but of course it has the downside that all photos get loaded when the user enters the page. The user does not see this, because the missing images are hidden in the overflow, but since some users are not even interested in my photos at all, there is a lot of unnecessary traffic generated.

My ideal solution would be something like this: I would like to mark some photos as "load immediately" (say the twenty first photos in the overflow) and all the remaining ones as "load dynamically" (all the remaining photos in the overflow). Now when the user scrolls through the overflow, the website should always try to "stay ahead" twenty photos of what the user has already seen so that he never notices the dynamic loading (so if the user has scrolled far enough in the DIV to have seen 7 photos, the website should dynamically decide to load photos 21 to 27, in addition to photos 1 to 20 that were already loaded right from the start because they were marked as "load immediately").

Is there an event that is fired once an image that was previously invisible because of overflow enters into the visible part of the DIV because of scrolling? Then I could react to this.

Or maybe you have some entirely different ideas how to approach this. I would like some "elementary" Javascript solution.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best solution but I use something like this 
<div onclick="scrollFunction()"></div> 
function scrollFunction(){ your code  }
To find out how much have you scrolled you can use element.scrollTop;

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [virtualization](https://blog.jscrambler.com/optimizing-react-rendering-through-virtualization/). There are some battle-tested solutions like [React Virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized).
You may also implement your own solution based on [Intesection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). However, this may require polyfilling unsupported browsers.